# parse json to struct from google api request in golang with App Engine

Tags: json, google-app-engine, go, urlfetch

i'm actually trying to use google map api in golang (in using urlfetch with app engine and when i execute a query i can not get the result in a structure.

my code

```
import (

   "google.golang.org/appengine"
   "google.golang.org/appengine/log"
   "google.golang.org/appengine/urlfetch"
   "net/http"
   "strings"
   "encoding/json"
    "encoding/gob"
    "bytes"
)

func GetCoordinatesByAddress(request *http.Request) bool {

    var results Results

    ctx := appengine.NewContext(request)
    client := urlfetch.Client(ctx)

    resp, err := client.Get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Suresnes+France"&key=" + ApiKey)
    if err != nil {
      return false
    }

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
    decoder.Decode(&results)
    log.Debugf(ctx, "", results)
}

type Results struct {
   results []Result
   status string
}

type Result struct {
   address_components []Address
   formatted_address string
   geometry Geometry
   place_id string
   types []string
}

type Address struct {
   long_name string
   short_name string
   Type []string `json:"type"`
}

type Geometry struct {
   bounds Bounds
   location LatLng
   location_type string
   viewport Bounds
}

type Bounds struct {
   northeast LatLng
   southwest LatLng
}

type LatLng struct {
   lat float64
   lng float64
}
```

Query results (with curl)

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Suresnes",
               "short_name" : "Suresnes",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Hauts-de-Seine",
               "short_name" : "Hauts-de-Seine",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Île-de-France",
               "short_name" : "Île-de-France",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "France",
               "short_name" : "FR",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "92150",
               "short_name" : "92150",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "92150 Suresnes, France",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 48.88276,
                  "lng" : 2.2364639
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 48.859284,
                  "lng" : 2.199768
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 48.869798,
               "lng" : 2.219033
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 48.88276,
                  "lng" : 2.2364639
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 48.859284,
                  "lng" : 2.199768
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJ584OtMVk5kcR4DyLaMOCCwQ",
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Query result (with my go code)

```
DEBUG: %!(EXTRA controlgoogle.Results={[] })
```

Could you help me to parse this query results in a structure ?

Thank's

Comment: it will help your debugging to comment out everything but the `status` field, the unmarshaller will happily discard unknown fields so it's a simpler test case. You can also log the request body with [`ioutil.ReadAll`](https://godoc.org/io/ioutil#example-ReadAll). You may want also want to try [`http.Get()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Get)

Comment: I'm using google appengine, it isn't possible to use http.Get

Answer (score 6):

To unmarshal a JSON to struct, it needs access to the members so that it can update the value. To allow access you have to export the members of the struct(By starting the member name by upper-case). The JSON fields should be mapped to struct's members as well using `json:"<field_name>"`. I have updated your structure.

```
type Results struct {
   Results []Result `json:"results"`
   Status string `json:"status"`
}

type Result struct {
   AddressComponents []Address `json:"address_components"`
   FormattedAddress string `json:"formatted_address"`
   Geometry Geometry `json:"geometry"`
   PlaceId string `json:"place_id"`
   Types []string `json:"types"`
}

type Address struct {
   LongName string `json:"long_name"`
   ShortName string `json:"short_name"`
   Types []string `json:"types"`
}

type Geometry struct {
   Bounds Bounds `json:"bounds"`
   Location LatLng `json:"location"`
   LocationType string `json:"location_type"`
   Viewport Bounds `json:"viewport"`
}

type Bounds struct {
   Northeast LatLng `json:"northeast"`
   Southwest LatLng `json:"southwest"`
}

type LatLng struct {
   Lat float64 `json:"lat"`
   Lng float64 `json:"lng"`
}
```

Comment: nice one, didn't know you needed either the decorator or an exported struct member

Comment: @Plato: you actually *must* have the fields exported, regardless of decorator.  The decorator is there to handle different field names (if your variable is named "UserID" while the field is named "user_id", for example).  The JSON library will automatically try to match fields that differ only in capitalization, but won't try for other variants like underscores, so you need the decorator for those case.  It can't do ANYTHING with your struct unless the fields are exported, though, because it can't even see the field.

Comment: Worth noting, however, that anonymous structs are always considered exported, so you can create a variable of an anonymous struct type and use that instead of actually defining an exported structure in your package.

Answer (score 2):

Watch out for the structs' fields case. If i remember correctly, lowercase fields will be ignored by the marshaller/unmarshaller so you're ending up in empty structs. Try naming the fields uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Struct fields that have json tags need to be exported (Uppercase field name). 
Also you should add json tags for all your struct fields, json tag must be identical to the json fields which you wanted to parse:

```
type Address struct {
    LongName  string   `json:"long_name"`
    ShortName string   `json:"short_name"`
    Type      []string `json:"types"`
}
a := `{
    "long_name" : "Suresnes",
    "short_name" : "Suresnes",
    "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
}`

var addr Address
err := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(a)).Decode(&addr)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", addr)


output: {LongName:Suresnes ShortName:Suresnes Type:[locality political]}
```

Comment: The JSON decoder will handle it fine if the only difference between field names is capitalization, so you don't, strictly speaking, need the JSON tags if it's just capitalization differences.  Not a bad idea to include them for clarity, though.

Answer (score 0):

By default encoding/json package marshal/unmarshal only exported fields, so you should change your structs to something like this, started with uppercase and has json:"" tag.

```
type Results struct {
   Results []Result `json:"results"`
   Status string `json:"status"`
}
```